# How do I test whether a given SQL Syntax is valid for an older version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, version, backwards-compatibility

I regularly end up developing on projects where either the Central Test server, or Prod server is an older version of SQL Server than my local install.

e.g. Prod is SQL Server 2014. Local install in SQL Server 2019.

Mostly that's fine, it just means I have to remember to only use old syntaxes. (:cry:)
But occasionally I forget which syntaxes are old. Ooops.

Obviously our test environments catch this, but it would be great to be able to tell my Local Server ... "only accept SS2014 syntax", and have these mistakes caught before they're committed/pushed.

I *thought* this was what [CompatibilityLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15) was supposed to do. But either it doesn't, or I'm using it wrong. *(See below)*

How **should** I achieve this? (*other* than just installing a different SQL version!)

---

Attempt so far:

- Run `ALTER DATABASE MyLocalProjectDB SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;` ([`120` represents SS2014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-dbcompats))
- Run `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = db_name();` to confirm that the previous command "worked".
- Run `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [ATableThatDoesExist]`, to see if the syntax is accepted. It was.

  - DROP IF EXISTS was [new to SS2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments):
  - > MSDN: IF EXISTS ... Applies to: SQL Server ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x) through current version).
  - [Additional Source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/ba-p/384562)

Why hasn't this worked?

Comment: Why not install SQL Server 2014 locally? If yo are developing locally, then you should be ensuring you have the same version of SQL Server installed locally as your production server; then you *can't* use features that aren't supporting in the older version.

Comment: Also Database compatibility and version are *not* the same. Some syntax that is added in a version of SQL Server is available regardless of the compatibility of the database. Like wise, syntax that is removed won't work. For example, despite that the ANSI-89 JOIN syntax was only deprecated in SQL Server 2008, you cannot use it in SQL Server 2012+ in a database with a compatibility of 100 or lower, because the syntax was removed in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Larnu because having multiple different version of SQL Server installed will be a PITA, especially if they're installed out-of-order. Obviously if that's the only option then sobeit, but it feels very much like it shouldn't be the only option.

Comment: @Larnu obviously I'm talking about "would a command it work on a SS2014 instance, with compat level set to 120?" :D

Comment: Like I said, Compatibility level != Version. You get *similar* behaviour, but not all of it is replicated.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, I know. And then you gave 2 examples of "it won't work if you try it on a DB whose compatibility level is set lower than its version." This is true, but not terribly interesting since I know that *my* Prod database has its compatibility level set to the normal value for its version.

Comment: @Larnu if they entirety of your point is "setting a SS2016 DB to compat level 120 doesn't give you all of the behaviour of SS 2014", then ... yes ... evidently ... I stated that I'd already tested that in the question!?

Comment: My point is that if you want to get the **same** behaviour on your local instance and production is you need to install the same version, as I stated in my original comment, @Brondahl . Installing SQL Server 2019 and then wondering why it doesn't behave like 2014 is because it *isn't* 2014. Otherwise, you'll need to check the documentation before you use features, as they may well not appear in the other version; or you need a good existing internal knowledge base of what you can (or perhaps) can't use. You can't precisely "emulate" SQL Server 2014 behaviour on SQL Server 2019.

Comment: `you need to install the same version, as I stated in my original comment` That's not something you stated previously; you merely advised it. But whatever.... If your answer is "it can't be done", then by all means post that as an actual answer.

Comment: *"Why not install SQL Server 2014 locally? ... then you can't use features that aren't supporting in the older version"* I'm quite clearly stating installing is an option here.

Comment: Yes ... ***an option*** .... not "the only way you can do this".

Comment: Which is why I went on to explain why your Compat level attempt didn't work, however, you seemed to not accept that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241582/discussion-between-brondahl-and-larnu).